# Can't connect to home wifi network, but can connect to phone hotspot

Tags: wireless

Today, after being away for two weeks, I suddenly found that my desktop machine will not connect to my home WiFi network. My phone connects successfully, and my desktop machine will connect to a hotspot on my phone.

I have tried forgetting and re-entering the information for the network, but it didn't help

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you rebooted your home WiFi / router?  Also, if you have, can you please edit your question and add a lot more details like the OS version you are using and any hardware details?  Details will help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist freq` and tell me what channels the router's wifi networks are set to. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Go into the wifi router settings and put it on a fixed channel from 1-11

Comment: Status please...